# Python - Encoding all possible 5-combinations into an integer

Tags: python, encoding, integer, combinations, binomial-coefficients

I've got a set of 25 integers, ranging from 0 to 24 and my application involves selecting 5 of them (there are no repeated values, no value can be selected more than once) obtaining a combination like this one **[15, 7, 12, 3, 22]**. It's important to consider the the previous combination is considered equal to **[7, 22, 12, 15, 3]**, the order doesn't matter, only the values do.

By applying the binomial coefficient (25 choose 5) we can find out that there are 53.130 possible combinations. I want to encode all the possible combinations into an integer so that all values from 0 to 53129 are linked to a combination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`more_itertools.nth_combination`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.nth_combination) that can compute the nth combination without computing all previous ones:

```
# pip install more-itertools
from more_itertools import nth_combination

nth_combination(range(25), 5, 0)
# (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

nth_combination(range(25), 5, 42)
# (0, 1, 2, 5, 7)

nth_combination(range(25), 5, 53129)
# (20, 21, 22, 23, 24)
```

You can make things more interesting by combining the above with [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)/[`cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache):

```
from functools import partial, cache

encode = partial(nth_combination, range(25), 5)
# or with a cache
# encode = cache(partial(nth_combination, range(25), 5))

encode(0)
# (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

encode(42)
# (0, 1, 2, 5, 7)

encode(53129)
# (20, 21, 22, 23, 24)
```

##### efficiency

The advantage of `nth_combination` is that for large ranges, it is not needed to compute all n-1 combinations to access the nth one. Also, it is not needed to store all combinations, making it both CPU and memory efficient. Combined with `cache` this makes a compromise between memory and CPU by avoiding to recompute the same value twice if the same code is requested several times.

However, if you must access **all** values eventually, then pre-computing all combinations [as show by @ti7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76744965/16343464) will be more straightforward and efficient, but will require to compute and store all values from the beginning:

```
from itertools import combinations

encode = list(combinations(range(25), 5))

encode[0]
# (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

encode[42]
# (0, 1, 2, 5, 7)

encode[53129]
# (20, 21, 22, 23, 24)
```

Answer (score 2):

With so few combinations, you could just compute every combination and keep them in a list to index from instead!

```py
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> cmb = list(combinations(range(25), 5))
>>> cmb[1], cmb[-1], cmb[-2]
((0, 1, 2, 3, 5), (20, 21, 22, 23, 24), (19, 21, 22, 23, 24))
>>> sys.getsizeof(cmb)
444376
```

Comment: Yes that's what I did, I computed every combination and kept them in a list using the function nth_combination which returns the combination that respect mt conditions (no repetitions)

Comment: @MaurizioBrini if you must compute all combinations, then `cmb = list(combinations(range(25), 5))` will be a more efficient approach. `nth_combination` will be more efficient if you have to access a few arbitrary positions (**and you shouldn't have to keep all combinations in a list!**). In the end, either approach is likely fast enough if you have a small number of combinations (50k is small).